# How can I read a csv file with unusual delimiters and encoding in R

Tags: r, csv, encoding, delimiter

I am trying to read a .csv file that uses an unusual delimiter *and* an unfamiliar (for me) encoding.

After much trial and error, I got the file to read at least, but the result is not very good. What can I do?

```
download.file('https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/kl8a86fiyim15g4op4er4/test_file.csv?rlkey=bx8mozu395r3zkl4ddka9fhsy&dl=1',
              destfile="test_file.csv",
              method="auto")

best_so_far <- read_delim(here("test_file.csv"), delim = '¤', 
                          locale = locale(encoding = "ISO-8859-1"), 
                          quote = "")
```

I did manage to import it to google sheets (where you can set a custom delimiter). It's har to know what google sheets does behind the scenes. Heres what it looks like:

```
7   150 3   2   2   99999998        99999998    99999998    99999998    99999998    99999998    99999998        3       99999998    99999998    99999998    99999998    99999998    99999998    99999998    99999998    99999998    99999998    99999998    99999998    99999998        99999998    99999998    99999998    99999998    99999998        99999998    99999998    99999998    99999998    99999998    99999998        99999998    99999998    99999998    99999998    99999998    99999998        99999998    17579   1 000 st 20 - 199   20-199 anställda    Bildelar & -tillbehör, partihandel  45310   100 64  STOCKHOLM
8   100 3   2   2   99999998        99999998    99999998    99999998    99999998    99999998    99999998        3       99999998    99999998    99999998    99999998    99999998    99999998    99999998    99999998    99999998    99999998    99999998    99999998    99999998        99999998    99999998    99999998    99999998    99999998        99999998    99999998    99999998    99999998    99999998    99999998        99999998    99999998    99999998    99999998    99999998    99999998        99999998    17579   1 000 st 20 - 199   20-199 anställda    Dagstidningsförlag  58131   100 64  STOCKHOLM
14  400 3   2   2   99999998        99999998    99999998    99999998    99999998    99999998    99999998        3       99999998    99999998    99999998    99999998    99999998    99999998    99999998    99999998    99999998    99999998    99999998    99999998    99999998        99999998    99999998    99999998    99999998    99999998        99999998    99999998    99999998    99999998    99999998    99999998        99999998    99999998    99999998    99999998    99999998    99999998        99999998    17579   1 000 st 20 - 199   20-199 anställda    Personal, uthyrning 78200   101 32  STOCKHOLM
```

It might be helpful to know that its supposed to be answers to, at least one, survey.

EDIT: Sample rows

```
7¤150¤3¤2¤2¤99999998¤¤99999998¤99999998¤99999998¤99999998¤99999998¤99999998¤¤3¤¤99999998¤99999998¤99999998¤99999998¤99999998¤99999998¤99999998¤99999998¤99999998¤99999998¤99999998¤99999998¤99999998¤¤99999998¤99999998¤99999998¤99999998¤99999998¤¤99999998¤99999998¤99999998¤99999998¤99999998¤99999998¤¤99999998¤99999998¤99999998¤99999998¤99999998¤99999998¤¤99999998¤17579¤1 000 st 20 - 199¤20-199 anställda¤Bildelar & -tillbehör, partihandel¤45310¤100 64¤STOCKHOLM
8¤100¤3¤2¤2¤99999998¤¤99999998¤99999998¤99999998¤99999998¤99999998¤99999998¤¤3¤¤99999998¤99999998¤99999998¤99999998¤99999998¤99999998¤99999998¤99999998¤99999998¤99999998¤99999998¤99999998¤99999998¤¤99999998¤99999998¤99999998¤99999998¤99999998¤¤99999998¤99999998¤99999998¤99999998¤99999998¤99999998¤¤99999998¤99999998¤99999998¤99999998¤99999998¤99999998¤¤99999998¤17579¤1 000 st 20 - 199¤20-199 anställda¤Dagstidningsförlag¤58131¤100 64¤STOCKHOLM
```

Comment: Could you open the file in a text editor and share the top couple lines (editing anything proprietary if necessary)? Many people here won't want to open a stranger's link on the internet, and links are liable to linkrot over time.

Comment: Result looks good although there is no header line in the CSV file (which is supposedly `cp1252` encoded).

Comment: add `col_names=FALSE` and you're much further, though I used `sep=\xa4` instead of the character displayed in the question (which only imported one column for me).

Comment: You can figure out the delimiter exactly if you stream bytes from the file in raw form, e.g. `bytes <- readBin(con = open("test_file.csv", "rb"), what = "raw", n = 11)` which should give you the first 11 characters. The second byte is probably your delimiter. You can check with `rawToChar(bytes)`

Comment: @JosefZ I tried your suggestion first, and that seems to do alot. Thanks. What is \xa4 exactly?

Comment: (edit to my previous comment) `sep='\xa4'` (adding quotes)

Comment: @JonSpring I added a little bit of code. JozefZ maybe solved it, but it's a bit too late for me to really check, I will return to it tomorrow.

Comment: @JosefZ And can you clarify if the header is encoded or not? Can you tell? What is cp1252?